C# XmlReader ignoring tags if no whitespace exists between them
I have an XML file with all the XML on one line as follows:
<route><name>CSX Atlanta Division Abbeville Sub</name><description>The Abbeville Subdivision runs from Tucker, GA to Abbeville, SC. It is a CTC-line, single track with passing sidings. There are four road trains, coal, grain, ethanol, and local traffic.</description><history>The Abbeville Subdivision was originally part of the Seaboard Air Line Railroad. With the creation of CSX in the early 1980s, the Abbeville Sub has remained a part of CSX since.</history><radio></radio></route>

It's output from an XmlWriter in this same program.
For some reason, XmlReader is skipping tags. It'll read the name tag, then skip description, then read history.
This is the reader code and the constants:
public class Constants
  {    
    public class Tags
    {
      public const string NAME = "name";
      public const string DESC = "description";
      public const string NOTES = "notes";
      public const string TYPE = "type";

      public class RouteTags
      {
        public const string ROUTE = "route";
        public const string HISTORY = "history";
        public const string HISTORYLINK = "historylink";
        public const string INDUSTRY = "industry";
        public const string LOCATIONINFO = "locationinfo";
      }
}

public void ReadXML(XmlReader textReader)
    {
      while (textReader.Read())
      {
        if(textReader.Name == Constants.Tags.NAME && textReader.IsStartElement())
        {
          Name = textReader.ReadElementContentAsString();
        }
        else if (textReader.Name == Constants.Tags.DESC && textReader.IsStartElement())
        {
          Description = textReader.ReadElementContentAsString();
        }
        else if (textReader.Name == Constants.Tags.RouteTags.HISTORY && textReader.IsStartElement())
        {
          History = textReader.ReadElementContentAsString();
        }
        else if(textReader.Name == TAG && !textReader.IsStartElement())
        {
          return;
        }
    }
}

This doesn't make any sense, why would it skip? Why doesn't it recognize the end tag of name and go to the start tag of description?
I've only been able to get this to read by manually adding whitepsace between the tags, either inline, or after doing a "pretty print" in Notepad++. One requirement of this program is to be able to read XML it has already written without user-intervention.

You are making this way more complicated than needed. You can simply query all the elements you need using Linq-to-Xml. See How to get elements by name in XML using LINQ

What is TAG? The code as quoted does not define this identifier.

Cannot reproduce https://dotnetfiddle.net/LORrHD it shows all tags as expected. I agree I really don't get why you are using this API.

As @Filburt notes XmlReader is the hardest of ..NET's XML APIs. It only makes sense if you must stream the input document (eg. it is huge). Any of the other APIs are far easier to use to extract information.

Your code does not compile. Please publish the code that anyone can copy and execute on their own.

@Charlieface you've assumed TAG should be a string! I suspect it is a member of RouteTags and the condition is leading to early exit when matched.

What is the size of your XML file?

While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
Please edit your original question and provide the following:
(1) Well-formed XML file sample.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic, and your code attempt trying to implement it.
(3) Desired output based on the sample data in #1 above.
All within the question as text, no images.

As it was already suggested by many, it is better to use LINQ to XML API. It is available in the .Net Framework since 2007 onwards.
Input XML
<route>
    <name>CSX Atlanta Division Abbeville Sub</name>
    <description>The Abbeville Subdivision runs from Tucker, GA to Abbeville, SC. It is a CTC-line, single track with passing sidings. There are four road trains, coal, grain, ethanol, and local traffic.</description>
    <history>The Abbeville Subdivision was originally part of the Seaboard Air Line Railroad. With the creation of CSX in the early 1980s, the Abbeville Sub has remained a part of CSX since.</history>
    <radio></radio>
</route>

c#
void Main()
{
    const string FILENAME = @"e:\Temp\MattCW.xml";

    const string ROUTE = "route";
    const string NAME = "name";
    const string DESCRIPTION = "description";
    const string HISTORY = "history";
    const string RADIO = "radio";

    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

    foreach (var xelem in xdoc.Descendants("route"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(xelem.Element(NAME)?.Value);
        Console.WriteLine(xelem.Element(DESCRIPTION)?.Value);
        Console.WriteLine(xelem.Element(HISTORY)?.Value);
        Console.WriteLine(xelem.Element(RADIO)?.Value);     
    };
}

Output
CSX Atlanta Division Abbeville Sub
The Abbeville Subdivision runs from Tucker, GA to Abbeville, SC. It is a CTC-line, single track with passing sidings. There are four road trains, coal, grain, ethanol, and local traffic.
The Abbeville Subdivision was originally part of the Seaboard Air Line Railroad. With the creation of CSX in the early 1980s, the Abbeville Sub has remained a part of CSX since.



I follow how to get the route data, but then how would that look for objects under route? Radio for instance is its own object and has for example  objects underneath it. I'm not following at all how to use this for child objects.

While working on the answer on your question, I used your XML sample in the original question. Please don't miss my comment about a minimal reproducible example

Yes, I know, I didn't have anything in the radio tag at the time because I didn't think this was going to spiral like this. Your solution works great for the route object by itself, but if I'm completely changing gears, I need to know how to make it work.

Please edit your original question and provide a minimal reproducible example.

Do you want my entire codebase or something? This is it, this is as minimal reproducible as I can give you. I don't see what your hang up is.

##1 and 3, you can skip #2

Try not using ReadElementContentAsString(). This method reads the entire content of the current element (including child elements if present) and moves the reader to the next node after the element’s end tag. So, when you call ReadElementContentAsString() on <name>, the reader moves past <name>, skipping over <description> without processing it.
You can modify your code to use XmlReader.Read() for each element instead of ReadElementContentAsString(), or you can simplify the reading process by structuring it differently. You can try something like this method XmlReader.ReadToFollowing() to locate each tag explicitly, which is more reliable for sequential reading.
public void ReadXML(XmlReader textReader)
{
    if (textReader.ReadToFollowing(Constants.Tags.NAME))
    {
        Name = textReader.ReadElementContentAsString();
    }
    if (textReader.ReadToFollowing(Constants.Tags.DESC))
    {
        Description = textReader.ReadElementContentAsString();
    }
    if (textReader.ReadToFollowing(Constants.Tags.RouteTags.HISTORY))
    {
        History = textReader.ReadElementContentAsString();
    }
}


Hi you can try this with XmlDocument c#.
Here is my solution for this.

Try to get XML content as string first.
you can use below code for that. ( using System | using System.IO)
string filePath = "path/to/your/file.xml";
string xmlContent = File.ReadAllText(filePath);


Use below method to read that xml string.
void ReadxmlContent(string xmlContent)
{
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.LoadXml(xmlContent);

    XmlNode routeNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/route");

    if (routeNode != null)
    {
        // Read "name" element
        XmlNode nameNode = routeNode.SelectSingleNode("name");
        string name = nameNode?.InnerText ?? "No name provided";
        Console.WriteLine("Name: " + name);

        // Read "description" element
        XmlNode descriptionNode = routeNode.SelectSingleNode("description");
        string description = descriptionNode?.InnerText ?? "No description provided";
        Console.WriteLine("Description: " + description);

        // Read "history" element
        XmlNode historyNode = routeNode.SelectSingleNode("history");
        string history = historyNode?.InnerText ?? "No history provided";
        Console.WriteLine("History: " + history);

        // Read "radio" element
        XmlNode radioNode = routeNode.SelectSingleNode("radio");
        string radio = radioNode?.InnerText ?? "No radio information provided";
        Console.WriteLine("Radio: " + radio);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Route information not found.");
    }
}



Try this way it will help to solve your problem.
